# Xamarin.Android work slowly when device is blocked

Tags: android, .net, xamarin

At the beginning I built an desktop application (**WPF in .NET Framework**) and Engine (**Class Library in .NET Framework**). Later I tried to built frontend for the Engine project in **Xamarin.Forms/Xamarin.Android**. I was suprised when I just added a reference to Xamarin project and everything worked fine.

The problem appears when I run my android application and block device using power button - application start to work 2-3 times slower. Even Task.Delay(1000) takes 1500-3000 ms to be executed.
I have internal timer in the Engine project and this problem causes time divergence between real-time and time inside Engine.

**The Engine project is multi-thread project. It creates and destroys many threads during work.**

What I have tried:

- using WakeLock.Partial.
- using Android.App.Service
- disabled battery power optimization
- all permissions for application
- add application to "whitelist" in device settings(work in background, ignore battery
  optimization options)

Application works fine on blocked device when the device is connected to power source.

Android Version: 10

Is it possible to keep CPU of android device running all time with full power? How to keep code exeuction at normal speed when device is blocked?

Comment: "...keep CPU of android device running all time with full power..." : The Linux kernel is responsible for this (and Android is NOT a real-time OS), i.e. If the device is in "locked" mode, then if the device contains a SoC that has "big" and "little" cores, your app's service-based/broadcast-intent threads would be moved to the little cores due to power management. But this is highly dependent upon the API-level of the device, the SoC used in the device and how the OEM has tuned the power-management features of Android.

Comment: One of the only things that can "somewhat" guarantee your app keeps running is using a foregrounded service (even this is somewhat OEM dependent). The reason you are seeing things like Task.Delay times increasing is the app is being paused by the OS. In the latest API-levels, having a full-time running service is becoming more and more restricted and as such your mobile app design should not be designed to require a full-time service (unless you are streaming (i.e. VoIP), music playback, etc...).

Comment: @prog777, According to your description, you mean that you debug xamarin.android on device,it works fine, but when device block, this project work very slowly?

Comment: @SushiHangover I built foreground service with notification. When I click button on notification I can see the system time and my Engine time. After waiting 1 minute in "lock" mode there is difference around 15 secs. I think may be caused by that the engine makes calculations on other threads, so foreground service does not helps (I am not an expert in android programming).

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT yes, when device is connected to PC USB port, app work fine also - not matter if the device is blocked or not. Do not work when the device is blocked and is not connected to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the **solution - WakeLock inside Foreground service**.
Foreground service alone was not enough.

With this combination the Engine works with normal speed when device is locked without connection to any source of power.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue by yourself, please remember to mark you reply as answer, thanks.